# jQuery how to add a class to an element one by one with a small delay?

Tags: jquery, element, delay, each, addclass

jQuery how to add a class to an element one by one with a small delay when click on the #button ?
not to add the class at once for all element.I want to do it one by one. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<ul id="scroll-set">
<li class="  imVisible">Brentwood</li>
<li class="imVisible ">Antioch</li>
<li class=" imVisible">Pittsburg</li>
<li class=" imVisible">Concord</li>
<li class="imVisible ">Walnut Creek</li>
<li class=" imVisible">Danville</li>
<li class=" imVisible">San Ramon</li>

</ul>
<div id="button">
```

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302824/animating-addclass-removeclass-with-jquery

Answer (score 15):

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/vbwtW/)***

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#scroll-set li').each(function(i) {
    var $li = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $li.addClass('imVisible');
    }, i*100); // delay 100 ms
  });
});
```

---

[***The reverse version.***](http://jsfiddle.net/vbwtW/2/)

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $($('#scroll-set li').get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    var $li = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $li.addClass('imVisible');
    }, i*100); // delay 100 ms
  });
});
```

​

Comment: However, I'd suggest to drop useless variable: http://jsfiddle.net/vbwtW/1/. Otherwise, that's +1.

Comment: @VisioN Yep, that's better :)

Comment: Thanks xdazz. This is what Im looking for.

Comment: A small question. How to start it from bottom instead of top?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setInterval`:

```
$(function(){
  var el = $('li');
  var index = 0;
  var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if  (index < el.length) {
      el-eq(index++).addClass('imVisible');
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bdUxa/

Answer (score 1):

do a settimeout with a delay and set the classname by the index and it should work.

```
var i=0;
function changeClass()
{
    if(i<document.getElementById("scroll-set").childNodes.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("scroll-set").childNodes[i].className= "whateverclassname";
        i++;
        setTimeout(changeClass,1000);
    }
}
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: It's Working. Thank you so much :) But my question was do it using jQuery. Anyway It doesn't matter. It works.