# Changing classes with animation depending on scroll position

Tags: jquery, class, scroll, jquery-animate, scrollbar

My page contains four sections, each set to 100% height with different background color. At the very top I have a fixed menu. I want the menu to change it's background color depending on which section the user is at the moment, so it blends better with the background.

So far I have managed to make the menu's bg color to change when portfolio is entered, but it's not much and I am stuck. It has to change it's color again, when the user scrolls back to home, forth to about and so on. Also, I want it to be animated, but I don't know how to use animate() with addClass(). I've been trying for the past two days with no success at all.

The other thing that tortures me is that the menu elements should respond to the scroll position too. For example, if the user scrolls from Home to Portfolio, the active class should be applied to Portfolio and removed from Home. Hope you got the idea.

So far my code looks like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home"></div>
    <div id="portfolio"></div>
    <div id="about"></div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
```

I have no idea why, but I can't post the css here without breaking the whole post, so just go to [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkaramitev/Dxtyu/) to see it all together.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.menu');
    var portfolio_position = $('#portfolio').offset().top;
    var about_position = $('#about').offset().top;
    var contact_position = $('#contact').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= portfolio_position) {
            menu.removeClass('menu').addClass('menu-light');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/1/

```
var menu = $('.m1');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var z = $('#portfolio').offset().top;

    if (y >= z) {
        menu.removeClass('menu').addClass('light-menu');
    }
    else{
        menu.removeClass('light-menu').addClass('menu');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working nice :) Still, do you have an idea how can I make the class changes animated?

Answer (score 0):

a slightly different approach is to check if the element is actually in view. I based this solution on a great little function provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/1807551 by Scott Dowding. You can easily set colors/classes for each div section using this technique.

Solution fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/YzM3Q/

CSS:

```
.menu { background-color: #ffffff; }
.menu-light { background-color: #cc0000; }
/* this lets you easily set colors by div section/class:
.porfolio-section-bg  { background-color: #cc0000; }
*/
```

jquery:

```
function isInView(elem){
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
$(document).ready(function () {
var menu = $('.menu');
    $(window).scroll( function () {
        if (isInView( $('#portfolio-section') ) ){
            menu.addClass('menu-light');
        }else{
            menu.removeClass('menu-light');
        }            

    });
});
```

Comment: Got the idea ;) I'll try it out! :)

Comment: great, if it worked for you, can i please get a vote up? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd6R2/29/).
I've assigned a different class to each div so you can see the transitions more easily.

Included the animations(from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302824/animating-addclass-removeclass-with-jquery) SO question), using this:

```
div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Added a new class to target the divs for hover.

```
<div class="hoverDiv" id="home">home<p></p></div>
```

Then for change event and class replacement, this jquery:

```
$('.hoverDiv').hover(function(){
    //adjust the menu background color
    removeMenuClasses();
    menu.addClass($(this).attr('id') + '-menu');
});

function removeMenuClasses(){
    var classNames = menu.attr('class').split(' ');
    for(var i = 0;i < classNames.length; i++){
        if(classNames[i].indexOf('menu') >= 0){
            menu.removeClass(classNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Scroll with this:

```
if (y >= contact_position) {
    menu.addClass($("#contact").attr('id') + '-menu');
}
else if (y >= about_position) {
    menu.addClass($("#about").attr('id') + '-menu');
}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Here: [**JSnippet DEMO**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/320/Changing-classes-with-animation-depending-on-scroll-position)

Using:

```
var menu = $('.m1');

$(window).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
var z = $('#portfolio').offset().top;

if (y >= z) {
    menu.removeClass('menu').addClass('light-menu');
}
else{
    menu.removeClass('light-menu').addClass('menu');
}
});
```

And:

```
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

Comment: I tried all suggestions and this worked best for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I can give you a credit somehow, let me know ;) I'm new to SO

Comment: Thank you - Just accept the answer and vote up.... note that the key is the menu background with the opacity - `background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);` have fun!!