# How to make this hovering navigation bar

Tags: html, navigation, navigationbar

So I've saw this website: http://unfold.no/
And I want to learn how to build navigation bar that is both transparent and can change color as function of background (if you scroll up or down you'll see it) .
I have limited experience with navigation bars that dates to old Dreamweaver versions, so forgive me for the generality of the question...  Any advise of where to start will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something similar like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color) would help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue can be solved by reading the answer on this question:

[Changing classes with animation depending on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237953/changing-classes-with-animation-depending-on-scroll-position)

Basically, in the example you are showing, the menu has a `position: absolute` on the page, which positions it on the top right corner of the page. Then, an easy way of changing the **color** of the menu is by swapping classes on the menu itself through Javascript. You can use the code shown on the link above to see how this is done.

By swapping classes regarding the element **colors** with animation, you then give each element a CSS `transition` just like this:

```
.object{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

This CSS will make your elements change **color** by fading with an animation duration of *0.5* seconds.

It is pretty simple if you know have a basic understanding of **CSS and Javascript**