# Blink the inputs of the form on server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form I am posting on server and if server respond with any errors I want slowly blink the inputs of the form (submits and textareas).

I was trying to do something like that:

JS:

```
 $(':input','#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').fadeOut(550, function(){
   $(':input','#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').toggleClass("blink-class").fadeIn(550);             
});
```

CSS:

.`blink-class { border: 1px solid #ee1b1b !important; }`

But it is just removed inputs from the form instead of blinking.
Basically I just want to blink the red border around the inputs but in a nice way.

Is there any ways of doing this?

Comment: You only want to blink the border without hiding the content? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Split Your Infinity yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var $els = $(':input', '#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');
    $els.fadeOut(550).promise().done(function () {
        $els.toggleClass("blink-class").fadeIn(550);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fa3cJ/)

Why?
The `:hidden` selector will cause your selector to ignore the elements whose display is set to `none` by the `fadeOut`. Also the `fadeOut` handler is executed multiple time(one time for each input element selected by your selector)

The solution is to cache the elements that are [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut), then [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) them inside a [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise).[done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) handler - it is because we need to display all the input elements at once when all the elements are faded out

Comment: In the demo elements disparaging and then appearing, Is it possible to do the same but without elements disappearing?

Comment: I mean by clicking the button the input should flash with a red border(border slowly gets red color and than red color slowly disparaging) but in your sample the input disparaging, if you add values to the inputs you will see it more clearly. I want just to blink the border without hiding the content.

Comment: heh great, but how to add `css` class insteard of adding just `border`?

Comment: @sreginogemoh try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fa3cJ/7/ but for both these samples to work you need to use jQuery UI

Comment: There is no way to add class when using `animate` function? Because then it is not animated it is looks wired.

Comment: @sreginogemoh no... animate function does not accept class as a parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302824/animating-addclass-removeclass-with-jquery do you have any idea how function `getClassContent` could looks like?

Comment: @sreginogemoh in that case the OP was asking whether such a method exists... but AFAIK it does not exists... but you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var t = null;

function blink() {
    var obj = $('input[type="text"]')
    obj.addClass("blink-class");
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        obj.removeClass("blink-class");
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            blink();
        }, 550);
    }, 550);
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/hzdsz/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

```
$(':input','#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').animate({borderColor: "#FF0000"}, 250)
    .animate({borderColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 250)
    .animate({borderColor: "#FF0000"}, 250)
    .animate({borderColor: "#000000"}, 250);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PFHy7/)**