# How to add CSS transitions to create open/close effect on a custom modal window

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, css-transitions

I have a `DIV` with default `display:none`. It uses the class `overlay` defined as:

```
.overlay
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:200;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:black;
}
```

Clicking a button, I simply add it the following class with jQuery:

```
.open {
  display:block;
}
```

As you can see, it is simply rendered as a full window overlay.

I would like to add some opening/closing effect and not simply toggle it's `display` property, (fade or translate, I don't know yet what).

I would like to use **CSS transitions** but how to add them in the correct way? The problem is obviously more evident at closing because I anyway need to apply `display:none;` at the end of closing transition.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302824/animating-addclass-removeclass-with-jquery

Comment: If you don't know what effect you want yet this is way too broad.

Comment: I can understand what you're saying but don't agree. I'm asking for general principle and not the complete solution. The main problem is how to combine need to toggle `none` and `block` for `display` and transition on other properties. As commented on User1111's solution changing `z-index` from `-1` could seem the exact trick

Answer (score 3):

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.open {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

I didn't try it but what I understand in CSS3 is we're not allowed to animate display property. That's why I put opacity and tried to change some style. Just try. Maybe try to check gsap tweenmax. Easy to use and much better in terms of performance.

Comment: Very interesting and simple solution. The key is `z-index:-1` as default. Just a puntualization: is necessary to remove `display:none` and `display:block`. I don't know why but with these properties, also opacity transition does not work (at least in Firefox)

Comment: In addition, it surely solve the problem at "opening". To have transition also on closing is necessary to set it to all properties, so: `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;`

Comment: @LucaDetomi maybe, you're right. What I always did is using oncomplete function in tweenmax to change the display value. Maybe just remove display because you already toggle the z-index. It's up to you. Depends on how you want your system works. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `show(x)` jQuery function, where x is the milliseconds you want the fade to last. And `.hide()` to hide the element.

See: http://api.jquery.com/show/ & http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I know this but as I wrote, I would like to use CSS transitions for optimal performances

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use transitions for open/close events, you have to use visibility instead of display. actually this issue is thoroughly diccussed in the following post:

[What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

and your answer is in one comment by Michael Deal:

> It's important to keep css-transitions into mind when talking about visibility vs. display. For example, toggling from visibility: hidden; to visibility: visible; allows for css-transitions to be used, whereas toggling from display: none; to display: block; does not. visibility: hidden has the additional benefit of not capturing javascript events, whereas opacity: 0; captures events. –
> Michael Deal